# AngularJS <select> for every object in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am creating a table from an array of objects. In every line I need to have  item, with prechosen value equal to the object name used in the line.
Problems are: 1. How to choose for every select a default value equal to `reader.owner_name` in each line.
<strike>2. how to understand what line was changed?</strike>

```
<tr class="restTable" data-ng-repeat="reader in readers|orderBy:'number'">
    <td> {{ reader.number }}</td>
    <td> {{ reader.type }}</td>
    <td ><select ng-model='$parent.selectedSupervisor' ng-options="ref.name for ref in referents |orderBy:'name'"  ng-change="change()"></select></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: For the 2. you have to specify the index in your ng-repeat: `reader in readers track by $index`. After this, you can send the `$index` in your change function: `change($index)`. This will link your object to your function.

Comment: the problem is that `$index` doesn't correspond to the index in the array `readers` as it is ordered

Comment: What is it corresponding then ?

Comment: Ok, this one was resolved using your solution but adding tracking by `reader.arrayindex` and using `change(reader.arrayindex)`, set was set previously. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can assign model value as below

   ```
    ng-model="reader.owner_name"
   ```

Comment: Nope, still blank in the beginning

Comment: You need to bind according to value in variable 'referents' .                                   Here ref.name should be equal to reader.owner_name. otherwise you can do something like this ng-options="option.STATE_SHORTNAME as option.STATE_LONGNAME for option in OpportunityStates"

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: make sure value in ref.name  should be equal to  what ever value you assign in mg-model. Otherwise you can use this syntax <select ng-options="item.subItem as item.label for item in items" ng-model="selected"></select>

Comment: I am not sure that I got it.
i used `ng-model='$parent.selectedSupervisor[reader.arrayindex]'` and now i may change single select and not all of them.
Then in controller I created function `function fillDropdown(){
   for (var i = 0; i < readers.length; i++) {
    $scope.selectedSupervisor[ind].name=readers[i].owner_name;    
          }
  }` I am sure that names are equal as have the same origin. However no effect....

Comment: It should be '$scope.selectedSupervisor[i]=readers[i].owner_nam‌​e;'   There should not be .name property after '$scope.selectedSupervisor[ind]'